# Confusion with rows and columns in Flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to use flexbox to make the following layout:

[image: my desired layout]

I wish the `.entry__main` content to act like a block item where the next hmtl block falls on to a different line within the parent column, which has the `entry__content` div. However this isn't happening (I am just learning flex so wish to use that) - my content isn't wrapping and my divs are appearing on the same row like so:

[image]

```css
.entry {
    display: flex;
    cursor: pointer;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 12px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #E3E3E3;
}

.entry__image {
  width: 50px;
  position: relative;
}

.entry__content {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  padding-left: 12px;
}

.entry__info {
  width: 30px;
}

.entry__main {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
}

.entry__text {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="entry">
    <!-- this is a column -->
    <div class="entry__image">
        <img src="profile-pic.jpg">
    </div>
    <!-- this is a column -->
    <div class="entry__content">
        <!-- I want "entry__main" to fill the horizontal and be two columns" -->
        <div class="entry__main">
            <div class="entry__text">
                <div>Here is some content</div>
                <div>Here is some content below</div>
            </div>
            <div class="entry__info">
                <img src="delete-icon.png">
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- I want "entry__main" to fill the horizontal and be two columns" -->
        <div class="entry__main">
            <div class="entry__text">
                <div>Here is some content</div>
                <div>Here is some content below</div>
                <div>Here is some content below like the date 01-01-2018</div>
            </div>
            <div class="entry__info">
                <img src="delete-icon.png">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Can someone show me how to make the `entry__main` div take up the whole row as desired... to see this in the "real world" here is a jsbin: http://jsbin.com/bitajejaxi/edit?html,css,output

Comment: So why do you have `display: flex` on `.entry__content` at all if you want `entry__main` div to take up the whole row? they will be default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The layout strategy you are using to arrange `.entry_main` does not actually require `display: flex` on the parent ;) since the parent only used to hold individual `.entry_main` elements on new lines. Removing it will generate the layout you intend:

```
.entry__content {
  flex: 1;
  padding-left: 12px;
}
```

```css
.entry {
    display: flex;
    cursor: pointer;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 12px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #E3E3E3;
  }

.entry__image {
  width: 50px;
  position: relative;
}

.entry__content {
  flex: 1;
  padding-left: 12px;
}

.entry__info {
  width: 30px;
}

.entry__main {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid #38c0c4;
}

.entry__text {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="entry">
 <!-- this is a column -->
 <div class="entry__image">
  [Foto]
 </div>
 <!-- this is a column -->
 <div class="entry__content">
  <!-- I want "entry__main" to fill the horizontal and be two columns" -->
  <div class="entry__main">
   <div class="entry__text">
    <div>Here is some content</div>
    <div>Here is some content below</div>
   </div>
   <div class="entry__info">
    X
   </div>
  </div>

  <!-- I want "entry__main" to fill the horizontal and be two columns" -->
  <div class="entry__main">
   <div class="entry__text">
    <div>Here is some content</div>
    <div>Here is some content below</div>
    <div>Here is some content below like the date 01-01-2018</div>
   </div>
   <div class="entry__info">
    X
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Otherwise, simply use `flex-wrap: wrap` on it, and `flex: 1 0 100%;` on `.entry_main` to ensure they expand to 100% width (hence forcing each item on new rows):

```
.entry__content {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex: 1;
  padding-left: 12px;
}

.entry__main {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 0 100%;
  border: 1px solid #38c0c4;
}
```

```css
.entry {
    display: flex;
    cursor: pointer;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 12px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #E3E3E3;
  }

.entry__image {
  width: 50px;
  position: relative;
}

.entry__content {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex: 1;
  padding-left: 12px;
}

.entry__info {
  width: 30px;
}

.entry__main {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 0 100%;
  border: 1px solid #38c0c4;
}

.entry__text {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="entry">
 <!-- this is a column -->
 <div class="entry__image">
  [Foto]
 </div>
 <!-- this is a column -->
 <div class="entry__content">
  <!-- I want "entry__main" to fill the horizontal and be two columns" -->
  <div class="entry__main">
   <div class="entry__text">
    <div>Here is some content</div>
    <div>Here is some content below</div>
   </div>
   <div class="entry__info">
    X
   </div>
  </div>

  <!-- I want "entry__main" to fill the horizontal and be two columns" -->
  <div class="entry__main">
   <div class="entry__text">
    <div>Here is some content</div>
    <div>Here is some content below</div>
    <div>Here is some content below like the date 01-01-2018</div>
   </div>
   <div class="entry__info">
    X
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply remove `display: flex` off `.entry__content` entirely. A `div`'s default is to take up a whole row (block).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `flex-direction` property.
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/#article-header-id-3

```
.entry__content {
  flex-direction: column;
}
```